# Program that rotates scanned PDF files automatically

Tags: pdf, scanning, rotate

Is there a program that automatically rotates scanned PDF files?

The PDF scans are usually old paper files that need to be inserted into the scanner any way the scanner will take it. Is there a program that will automatically detect the correct way the PDF should be and adjust it properly?

These are old documents and unfortunately it cannot be as simple as scanning all the documents the same way because of rips, tears and the machine not taking the document.

It could run on Windows or Linux. Interested in open source, but more more interested in the reliability of the program. Price is non factor.

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of tools to rotate pdf's, from tiny scripts to full featured GUI based platforms. A simple google search gives me over 100, and 4 of these are actually in applications I already have (but didn't know)

The challenge you have is identifying the "correct way up" because there is no such thing. For a scan, unless you program in some image analysis that looks for the features you want to align, this makes no real sense.

Your best bet is to load all the paper the same way, so that step is not necessary, and then just script the rotation. This sort of thing is one of the menial tasks often given to junior interns.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote for your apparent lack of empathy for junior interns. But somebody already seems to have done that ;) so you get a +1 for pointing out that there might be no (generally) correct way to rotate all pdfs.